# Why do scalars and fermions have a different result in a Lagrangian?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, fermions, dirac-equation, klein-gordon-equation

Consider the Lagrangian for Yukawa theory:

$$
\mathcal{L} =i\bar{\psi}\not{\partial}\psi- \bar{\psi}m_F \psi +\frac{1}{2} \partial_\mu \phi \partial^{\mu} \phi - \frac{1}{2}m_s^2 \phi^2 + \mathcal{L}_{int}$$

The fermion and scalar are treated differently in three ways:

1. The scalar has a factor of 1/2
2. The scalar has $m^2$ as opposed to $m$
3. The scalar has "two derivatives" as opposed to one.

Is there an intuitive explanation for each of these? For example, it is clear that to form a scalar for the Lagrangian we will need to take two derivatives of the scalar $\phi$. But can anything more be said?

Comment: Are you asking why Dirac's equation is first order?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I understand why the Dirac equation itself is first order, my question is why do we combine the Lagrangians in this specific way? In other words, for example, what if the relative factor of 1/2 weren't there?

Comment: The $1/2$ is just a conventional normalization. It is not essential.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is no very intuitive way to explain it, which is not surprising given how long it took us to discover fermion fields. The point is that the Lagrangian must be a scalar Lorentz invariant. For scalar fields this is simple, they transform trivially so $\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi$, where you contract both derivatives, is a Lorentz scalar, so it's a valid candidate to add to the Lagrangian. Obviously $m \phi^2$ is also trivially a scalar invariant.

Now, you can ask, besides scalar fields what other fields can you have in the Lagrangian? More accurately, you can ask what are the irreducible representations (irreps) of the Lorentz group? These are the objects which transform 'covariantly'. For example, vector fields (electromagnetic potential $A^\mu$) and tensor fields (gravitational metric $g_{\mu \nu}$). These are all boson fields. In fact, a careful study of the Lorentz irreps leads also to fermion fields. But they transform in a somewhat more complex way than boson fields. So how do you contract fermion fields to get a scalar? You can make use of the gamma matrix $\gamma^\mu$ which has the property of transforming as a vector, when multiplied by fermion fields. That is, $\bar{\psi} \gamma^\mu \psi$ transforms as a vector, so if you contract $\gamma^\mu$ with a derivative $\partial^\mu$ you have $\bar{\psi} \gamma^\mu {\partial_\mu} \psi$ which is a scalar! I'm glossing over a lot of details here but this is the general idea.